# Show info dialog based on value of selected grid line

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In the prospects form (`smmBusinessRelationsListPage`) i want to make a modification for the following:

If a grid line is selected and CheckboxA of that line is checked, then show a dialog: "Checkbox is checked!"

My first thought is to build this check in the `active()` method of the form `smmBusinessRelationsListPage`

What is the best way to accomplish this? Do i need a specific function to check the line?

Or would:

```
if (checkboxA == true) {
info ("Checkbox checked!");
}
```

be enough to check the selected line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smmBusinessRelationsListPage` is (as the name says) a [list page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616937.aspx), which uses a query as its data source. That means that you can't overwrite the `active` method of the tables in the data source. Instead take a look at the interaction class of the list page, `smmBusinessRelationsListPageInteraction` (which is defined in the `InteractionClass` property of the root node of the form). This class already overwrites the `selectionChanged` method of its parent and this is the place where you would check for the state of the checkbox field.